# Cannot push into an array from Mongoose then statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

**Background**: A `Market` collection has a `url` property that stores an array of urls from selected `sites` from the `Site` collection. I created a helper (code below) that I could call from `/routes/markets.js` that essentially selects the `Market` based on `req.params.url` and then loops over the `market.sites` array and finds the corresponding `Site`, storing them into an array that I can use when the view is rendered.

**Issue**: Calling the `push` function on the array doesn't actually push anything and in the last `console.log` statement I have simply logs `[]`

**Question**: How can I push into this array? Is this an issue with the `for of` loop and `then` `Promise` call?

**market-helpers.js**

```
exports.listSites = (req, res, errorRender, successRender) => {
  let sites = [];
  Market.find({url: req.params.url})
    .then((market) => {
      for (url of market[0].sites)
        Site.find({url}).then((site) => {
          sites.push(site[0]);
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));

      console.log(sites);
      res.render(successRender, {sites});
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      res.render(errorRender, {errors});
    });
};
```

**routes/markets.js**

```
router.get('/:url', (req, res) => {
  Markets.listSites(req, res, 'login-markets', 'markets/index');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Site.find({url})` is an async operaration therefore `res.send` is executed before waiting for the result of async operation. You can wait for result of all async operations using `Promise.all` and once all of them are resolved you can return the response as follow:

```
exports.listSites = (req, res, errorRender, successRender) => {
  let sites = [];
  Market.find({url: req.params.url})
    .then((market) => {
      const promises = [];
      for (url of market[0].sites)
            promises.push(Site.find({url}).then((site) => sites.push(site[0])));

      return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
          console.log(sites);
          res.render(successRender, {sites});
      });
    })
    .catch((errors) => {
      res.render(errorRender, {errors});
    });
};
```